# Thick horizontal line detection

Tags: line, computer-vision, detection

Please suggest me some methods on thick horizontal line detection in images.
Any papers, libraries etc please.

Comment: Can you please give some sample images/  sample senarios/etc because the approach is highly dependent on the sort of interference present. It is just simple lines a hough transform could work.

Comment: I want to detect the plates (dishes) on image, by detecting thick lines that are the part of dish's boundary. They are thick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary threshold the image, then use a combination of morphological operations to detect "borders that are thicker then N1 but thinner than N2" to produce several images and combine (logically AND) them to selectively detect borders of a certain expected thickness.

Comment: do you mean opening and closing operations?

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit about "using a combination of morphological operations to detect "borders that are thicker then N1 but thinner than N2" to produce several images and combine (logically AND) them" as you answered above? Basically, I am trying to devise a morphological pattern to detect thick lines in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/xSHeYQz.png) but NOT those three connected symbols. How can I bypass them? Thx

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a good library. You may use a [Hough transform](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm#decl_cvHoughLines) to detect lines.

Note that the answer may depend on the quality of your images, some methods can be more effective that other ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the line images are really easy to detect (say you can find the line from ten yards away), just scale the image from (width, height) to (1, height) and find the y-coordinate of the darkest pixel. Use CV_INTER_AREA when resizing.

Comment: The idea is really good, to resize image so that the line will not be thick any more, but you are talking a little bit about different thing.
Why resizing is made until (1, height) ?
There can be many thick lines in image.

Comment: Resizing to (1, height) is equivalent to computing a single slice of the Hough transform at zero degree for the detection of strictly horizontal lines. Hough transform should be used with a carefully chosen set/range of angles for slightly-off horizontal lines.

Comment: Seeing erjik's new comment, I realize my answer is totally irrelevant. Please disregard. I posetd a new answer.