# OpenCV: How to detect thick red lines and their contours from the picture provided

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

What solution you could suggest to detect thick red lines and their contours from the pictures attached? I use OpenCV.
Thank you in advance!

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Comment: this post would be of some help: [thick horizontal line detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146196/thick-horizontal-line-detection)

Answer (score 0):

You could threshold the image to remove all the bright white/yellow pixels.
If the position is always approximately the same then the large remaning blob (in the red channel) on the right side of the image is your line.

Answer (score 0):

Use adaptive threshold in red channel to binary the image 
then use cvFindContours to fine each Couture. 
To be sure that each contour is belong to one on thick lines you want you can use Bounding boxes. use cvMinAreaRect2 to find each contour Bounding box and check there width and height to near to size on red lines if there match there are lines if else there are noise.